serilog log different format between .net core 6 and .net core 8 for http sink (problem in http sink after 7.2.0 version)
I am using http sink of serilog. previously my logs was sent to my http log end point like following
{
  "events": [
    {
      "Timestamp": "2024-09-11T13:22:00.8350743+01:00",
      "Level": "Information",
      "MessageTemplate": "User profile is available. Using '{FullName}' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.",
      "RenderedMessage": "User profile is available. Using '\"C:\\Users\\kamran.shahid\\AppData\\Local\\ASP.NET\\DataProtection-Keys\"' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.",
      "Properties": {
        "FullName": "C:\\Users\\kamran.shahid\\AppData\\Local\\ASP.NET\\DataProtection-Keys",
        "EventId": {
          "Id": 63,
          "Name": "UsingProfileAsKeyRepositoryWithDPAPI"
        },
        "SourceContext": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager"
      }
      ]
 }

now after updating my project to .net 8 my logs are sending in this format
[
  {
    "Timestamp": "2024-09-11T12:10:51.2656227Z",
    "Level": "Information",
    "MessageTemplate": "User profile is available. Using '{FullName}' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.",
    "RenderedMessage": "User profile is available. Using '\"C:\\Users\\kamran.shahid\\AppData\\Local\\ASP.NET\\DataProtection-Keys\"' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.",
    "Properties": {
      "FullName": "C:\\Users\\kamran.shahid\\AppData\\Local\\ASP.NET\\DataProtection-Keys",
      "EventId": {
        "Id": 63,
        "Name": "UsingProfileAsKeyRepositoryWithDPAPI"
      },
      "SourceContext": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager"
    }
  }
]

any idea what could be wrong
Problem seems to be in http sink version after 7.2.0 version.
9.0.0, 8.0.0 all having this problem

did you update the version of serilog?

in net 8 some updates are made in request processing and routing as well i think it should be because of this

any how i can  send my log entries in events : ..... format

This change occurred in Release v8.0.0-beta.11. You can see the Release Notes, and the code for old versions, here.
The code that produced your old payload was in DefaultBatchFormatter.cs (which implemented IBatchFormatter) and looked like this:
public override void Format(IEnumerable<string> logEvents, TextWriter output)
{
    // snip
    output.Write("{\"events\":[");

    // snip
    foreach (var logEvent in logEvents)
    {
        // snip
    }

    output.Write("]}");
}

This file was removed in this changeset in favour of ArrayBatchFormatter.cs (also implementing IBatchFormatter), for which the equivalent code looks like this:
public void Format(IEnumerable<string> logEvents, TextWriter output)
{
    //snip
    output.Write("[");

    //snip
    foreach (var logEvent in logEvents)
    {
        //snip
    }

    output.Write("]");
}

The primary README.md file was changed at the same time. You can see the diff below:

So the short answer to "How can I send my log entries in the previous format" is that you can't, at least not without overriding some classes or forking the code. This was a breaking change (albeit one covered only obliquely by the Release Notes, at least as far as I can see) and unfortunately you will need to adapt your code and payload consumers accordingly.

If you still want to use the old formatter, it's implementation can be found here: https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http/wiki/Batch-formatters#custom-formatter-2---defaultbatchformatter
